# How can I create a shortcut to launch a batch file one folder up?

Tags: windows, batch-file, shortcut

I have been trying to create a shortcut to launch a batch file one folder up from the shortcut location.
I have been able to do this using and intermediate batch file in the same folder as the shortcut as follows:
Intermediate.bat:

`@echo off
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO set curdrv=%%~dpV
start "" %curdrv%Oneup.bat`

And the shortcut target is:
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c Intermediate.bat

and the 'Start in' is left blank.

This way I can move these folders anywhere on the drive or another drive and the shortcut still works.
However, I would like to leave out the Intermediate.bat file and launch the Oneup.bat directly. I tried:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO set curdrv=%%~dpV && start "" %curdrv%Oneup.bat
```

in the Target of the shortcut, but it doesn't work.

Is there some trick to getting this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" "..\Oneup.bat"

This is placed in the shortcut target with start in being left empty.